# Email users based on results of choice column with checkboxes (multiple selections)

Tags: sharepoint-server, workflow, column, email

I am looking to create a workflow that sends an email to users based upon the results of column that allows multiple selections. The column has 8 selections and it basically needs to email user "A" if option 1 is selected, user "B" if option 2 is selected, and users "A" and "B" if options 1 and 2 are selected (and so on).

My initial thought was to create a column that converted the results to text and then another based on that, but the formula started to get too complicated.

Is there an easier way of accomplishing this?

I'm also using DFFS on the SharePoint.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a Lookup or Calculated column to auto-populate the users/email addresses in this list.

But of course you will have to write the relationship between the Multi-Choice column and the users/email addresses in another list or in the Calculated column formula.

There is no easy way for this request to begin with (in SharePoint), but it will reduce the workload in the workflow.